# What can be a reason for getting empty svn repository after loading dump file?

Tags: svn, version-control, split, repository, tortoisesvn

[image: command line shows that they are loaded successfully but when i check the repository its size is increased and there is not loaded folder in it]

[image: creating dump file]

[image: filtering dump file and loading]

I am trying to split the existing svn repository since it has multiple projects in it. I want to have separate repositories for each. However last step of splitting which is loading filtered dump file to new repository i have a problem that they are loaded successfully but somehow I do not see them. Any idea why this happens?

Thanks beforehand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see transactions getting committed. How are you accessing that new *repository*? Are you starting svnserve on that directory? Are you using `file:///`?

Do you have svnlook on your system? We can use that to query that particular directory. Since we're in that directory, it's pretty simple:

```
$ svnlook youngest .
```

This should print out the last revision of that repository. It should agree with your svnadmin load.

```
$ svnlook tree .
```

This should print out the entire directory tree of your repository.

If that doesn't work. Try these:

```
$ svnlook log .
```

That will print out the last log message.

```
$ svnlook changed
```

Prints out what was changed.

If `svnlook tree .` doesn't print out anything, it's possible that the dump was filled with empty revisions. This is especially true if you used `svndumpfilter` to filter out transactions you didn't like.

If the repo does have transactions according to `svnlook`, use svnserve to run a local copy of your repo:

```
$ svnserve -r .
```

Then open another window, and try this:

```
$ svn log -v svn://localhost
```

And see if that prints out a log of your transactions.

---

## Addendum

I see what you have, and you can see that it dropped your tags, branches, and even trunk.

It looks like the problem is that you didn't specify what you thought. When you specify `include A`, you're specifying files that are at the ROOT of the repo.

You have:

```
$ svndumpfilter include A < repo.dump > A.dump
```

What you want to do is something like this:

```
$ svndumpfilter include trunk/A tags/A branches/A < repos.dump > A.dump
```

Note how you have to give the ***full path*** name of directory tree you want to include. You might be able to do something like this:

$ svndumpfilter include --pattern "*/A" < repo.dump > A.dump

Your dump shows you all of the directories that were **excluded** by `svndumpfilter`. You can use that to verify you're keeping what you think your keeping.

Comment: I use TortoiseSVN it has GUI for repo-browser, it shows nothing in trunk folder.

Comment: svnlook youngest gives me 28. i think i have committed 3 times, i am not sure it is because of this or not. svnlook tree just shows me branch tags trunk, and svnlook log shows : This is an empty revision for padding

Comment: It appears that you're creating empty changes in the repo for padding purposes. This is usually the result of you filtering a SVN dump while loading it, but not renumbering the transactions. TortoiseSVN will show nothing in the trunk, but if you ask for a log for trunk, you'll see 28 empty revisions for padding. Are you filtering your dump?

Comment: yes i need to filter the dump file before loading to create new repository for each project. I want to keep the same revision numbers for the projects and empty revision number if it is related to another project. Renumbering will ruin what i want right?

Comment: The issue then is your filtering via `svndumpfilter`. Can you update your question to show how you created your dump, or are filtering your dump when doing a load? The biggest issue is someone using pattern matching on Unix using --pattern, and forgetting the quotes around the globbing pattern. In that case, the Unix shell will attempt to replace the glob pattern with a file name, and that will cause the dump not to get filtered correctly.

Comment: I edited the question (second picture is creating dump file procedure and third picture is for filtering and loading the dump file)

Comment: See the **Addendum** on my answer.

Comment: thank you very much, i tried it with test repository, it worked. But there is one more issue about renamed projects. it shows invalid copy source path trunk/older_name when i try to filter the dump file. Can i solve this?

Comment: In that case, you may need to include the original location. For example, I moved /trunk/foo to /trunk/bar, I may need both directories in my include. You can try [svndumpfilter3](http://furius.ca/pubcode/pub/conf/bin/svndumpfilter3.html) which suppose to solve this problem.